# when making a private variable in. js and in vscode with # before var name the save separates it

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I use vs code . and when I try to make a private variable for class with #Var name , when saving the file the vs code separates the # and the Var and it doesn't allow me to make private variable .

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what you're seeing is some kind reformat-on-save. This could be caused by a linting plugin such as eslint or jslint or prettier. In its default configuration, VS Code won't change the contents of your file.

Here are some things to try to diagnose the problem:

- in your preferences, disable "Format On Save"
- look through your extensions and disable any that are related to coding styles; you will probably have to restart VS Code for this to take effect

Once you've figured out which plugin is causing this, you'll have to decide whether to change your style settings to permit this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. The solution for me was to uninstall some deprecated extensions in VS Code and then press reload.

Comment: which extensions? you can check your ~/.vscode/extensions folder for remnants of uninstalled extensions if you forgot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

There are no private variables in js the Symbol “#” is used so the others that work on same project can know, they r not supposed to touch this variable https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields
Here you can read about it

Comment: This does not seem correct. The linked page says, "There is however an experimental proposal to allow defining private class fields using a hash # prefix is added." And also, "The encapsulation is enforced by the language. It is a syntax error to refer to # names from out of scope."

Comment: the issue im facing is that when saving the vs Code separats the # and the name always